# Mysterious PHP upload limit despite correct php.ini settings

Tags: php, jquery, apache, .htaccess, upload

I have read tons of threads and **done all the recommended php settings**, but for some reason uploads only work when they are not larger than **exactly 128 MB**.

These are my settings via local .htaccess (but apache2/php.ini has the same values):

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 3800M
php_value post_max_size 3900M
php_value memory_limit 2048M
php_value max_input_time 3000
php_value max_execution_time 7200
```

This should really do the job, and the script outputs these values to check that they do apply (and they are being applied). This is our own server, Debian 7.1 64 bit with 16 GB Ram. The upload script is a combination of jquery and PHP (http://tutorialzine.com/2013/05/mini-ajax-file-upload-form/).

EDIT - ANSWER:

mod_security docs has a SecRequestBodyLimit default value of 128 MB, I raised it and it works!
Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked any webserver limits?

Comment: Display phpinfo() just before your upload to check that any library or class is changing these parameters. If you use a CMS (like Joomla, Drupal), these values can be overridden by the CMS.

Comment: First of all dump those values inside of the script to see if the changes from .htaccess are working:

var_dump(ini_get('upload_max_filesize'));

and so on.

Comment: So may be it's your jQuery uploader which fails somehow? To check: try to upload in "usual" way and see what'll happen

Comment: How do I check webserver limits? I know the standard config files, but what would I be looking for? 

I do have a complete phpinfo() printout and know that the values are being applied. I am not using Joomla, Drupal or the like.

Comment: What PHP version are you using? Either way: I note you're setting it to 3800M; please be aware that current PHP versions have an upper limit of 2gig on file uploads. Possibly the 3800M is being seen as invalid, and thus reverting to default. Note: When PHP 5.6 is released, [it will be able to upload larger files](http://www.phpdeveloper.org/news/20645), but current versions are restricted to 2gig max, and 5.6 won't be out for a while yet so if you need larger than 2gig, you may have to work out some kind of chunking mechanism to break it up into smaller parts before sending it.

Comment: For an Apache webserver, the `LimitRequestBody` may limit upload file sizes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use PHP with Suhosin patches and extension? If yes it is possible that Suhosin is configured to block large uploads.

Update: As commented below mod_security has a default SecRequestBodyLimit value of 128 MB.

Comment: Just checked, I don't think so, "suhosin" appears nowhere on the phpinfo() printout. Is there any part of this info to check in particular, apart from the obvious variables that I listed above?

Comment: If you have PHP 5.4+ then you don't have suhosin. Otherwise it should be right under the first table where it says "This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:"

Comment: Ok, I have PHP Version 5.4.4, but Suhosin is actually active, the text you state is shown! Any ideas how Suhosin needs to be configured or where the limit may be?

Comment: Just realized, I have no suhosin.ini anywhere on the system. I also removed it with 'aptitude purge php5-suhosin', but still get the "makes use of the Zend..." text.

Comment: For example `suhosin.post.max_value_length`

Comment: Suhosin is a set of patches to PHP and an extension. You removed the extension, the patches are still there. You cannot remove them without recompiling PHP,

Comment: Thanks, but without suhosin.ini anywhere to be found, where would this variable you posted be set?

Comment: It could use a default value

Comment: By the way, do use mod_php or FastCGI ?

Comment: I use mod_security, and mod_php5 is shown in phpinfo as a loaded module. Fastcgi is not shown. If it uses a default value, what can I do, create a suhosin.ini or something?

Comment: mod_security docs say SecRequestBodyLimit has a default value of 128 MB.